# How to get twitter engagement rate and tweets details using api in php?

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am trying to get tweet(s) details and engagement rate using twitter API in php https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=[screen_name]

But using above details i get some basic user details and last tweet details by user.

Anyone have idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get engagement in `api.twitter.com`

You have to use `data-api.twitter.com`

> https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/metrics/get-tweet-engagement/overview

You can get `engagement`, `impressions`, and lot more.

Comment: do we need to have gnip account for that?

Comment: As I already have enterprise account , but when I do request for this giving error.